# Why is it called spit roast?

Tags: history

Why is a spit called a spit? I can't imagine it, but historically, was it spat on?

Comment: Only for flavor ;)

Comment: @GdD: I hope they ate mint before :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotisserie:

> Rotisserie is a style of roasting where meat is skewered on a **spit** – a long solid rod used to hold food while it is being cooked over a fire in a fireplace or over a campfire, or roasted in an oven.

A **spit** is a long solid rod :) (as confirmed by http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spit#Noun)

Comment: And to fully clear up the linguistic question, the spit that you roast meat on [comes from a root meaning "sharp point"](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=spit), whereas spit in the sense of saliva comes from a root which is probably onomatopoeic.